# Copy the structure of an R object with slots (but not the data)

Tags: r

I would like to copy the structure of an R object which is a list with slots.

Can this be done either to produce a replica R object with no data, or with all the data replaced with NA?

Here is an extremely simplified version of an R list object with slots as an example:

```
setClass("Car",representation=representation(
   price = "numeric",
   numberDoors="numeric",
   typeEngine="character",
   mileage="numeric"
))
aCar <- new("Car",price=20000,numberDoors=4,typeEngine="V6",mileage=143)
obj <- list(test1="testing",test2=aCar)
```

Replacing each slot manually with NA will not work, as this is a simplified version... Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: `list`s don't have slots, so i'm not exactly sure what you want, `lapply(obj, function(x) if (isS4(x)) new(class(x)) else NA)`?

Comment: I have lists that appear to contain slots, as in the above example (unless I am not using the right terminology)...  List of 2
 $ : chr "testing"
 $ :Formal class 'Car' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
  .. ..@ price      : num 20000
  .. ..@ numberDoors: num 4
  .. ..@ typeEngine : chr "V6"
  .. ..@ mileage    : num 143           But your suggestion seems to do the trick - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One can write a `copy` method that makes a copy and then sets slots to `NA`. But as assigning just `NA` is not so easy, one may explicitly allow logical via a class union:

```
## numeric cannot contain just NA
setClassUnion("numeric_or_NA", c("numeric", "logical"))
setClassUnion("character_or_NA", c("character", "logical"))

setClass("Car",representation=representation(
  price = "numeric_or_NA",
  numberDoors="numeric_or_NA",
  typeEngine="character_or_NA",
  mileage="numeric_or_NA"
))

setGeneric("copy", function(obj, ...) standardGeneric("copy"))

setMethod("copy", "Car",
  function(obj, ...) {
    for (s in slotNames(class(obj))) slot(obj, s) <- NA
    obj        
  }
)

aCar <- new("Car",price=20000,numberDoors=4,typeEngine="V6",mileage=143)
obj <- list(test1="testing",test2=aCar)
otherCar <- copy(aCar)
str(otherCar)
```

**Edit**

An alternative is to check the classes of the slots and convert `NA` to the correct type:

```
setClass("Car",representation=representation(
  price = "numeric",
  numberDoors="numeric",
  typeEngine="character",
  mileage="numeric"
))

setGeneric("copy", function(obj, ...) standardGeneric("copy"))

setMethod("copy", "Car",
          function(obj, ...) {
            s  <- getSlots(class(obj))
            nm <- slotNames(class(obj))
            for (i in 1:length(s)) {
              slot(obj, nm[i]) <- as(NA, s[i])
            }
            obj        
          }
)

aCar <- new("Car", price=20000, numberDoors=4, typeEngine="V6", mileage=143)
obj <- list(test1="testing",test2=aCar)
otherCar <- copy(aCar)
str(otherCar)
```

One final question: why do you want to copy objects and not just instantiate it with `new` from the class?

Note also that R has also several other class systems besides S4 that are even more prototype based (classless).

Comment: I am not creating the objects, but importing them. The list r object (with slots) is something that is premade and I am importing into the workspace so that I can create plots using the data. There is one of these objects per species/year. However, some species/year objects are not available, so I want to copy the object for that species from a different year. The 'architecture' of the object needs to be the same, but with no data (or with NA).

Comment: But I assume you should have access to the class definition?